# Regex - Extracting img src from HTML

Tags: c#, html, regex, image, extract

I know I should not use regex in HTML.
I would like to extract image sources from an HTML file, example below:

It might look like this:

```
<img src = cid:header width="700" height="93" alt="Logo" />
<img src= cid:header width="700" height="93" alt="Logo" />
<img src =cid:header width="700" height="93" alt="Logo" />
<img src=cid:header width="700" height="93" alt="Logo" />
```

**In each case, I'ld like to get "cid:header" as the result.**

Since my regex knowledge is basically zero, I turn to you guys.
I need a pattern that accepts a space after "src" or after the "=" character.

**src[mightBeSpace]=[mightBeSpace]cid:[mustNotBeSpace]**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^<img src\s?=\s?([^\s]+).*/>$
```

Comment: I've provided this as-is to match one line of txt that contains only what you've provided.  Be aware (as pointed out by @Kolink) that RegEx is horrible at matching HTML

Comment: src\s?=\s?([^\s]+) this is the only party I needed, thank you!

Comment: please mark as answer if you believe it sufficiently answered your question

Comment: I will, as soon as it will let me.

Answer (score 2):

"might be space" in regex is `\s*`, and "must be no space" translates to `\S+`

Using this information you should be able to build a regex. If you can't, please show what you've tried.